# changing the name of a column in postgresql database

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm trying to modify the name a column named "photo_url". I tried to simply changing the string name to "test" and killing the postgresql service and then re starting it again, but it doesn't seem to be working; it still loads up as "photo_url".

I'm not sure how to change the name if anyone could help me it would be greatly appreciated.

this is my table im using postgreSQL, and pgweb to view my database, i used dbdesigner to generate this schema

```
CREATE TABLE "users" (
    "user_id" serial NOT NULL,
    "name" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "instrument" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "country" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "state" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "city" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "about" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "email" TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "hashed_password" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "photo_url" TEXT NOT NULL,
  "created_at" timestamptz NOT NULL default now(),
    CONSTRAINT "users_pk" PRIMARY KEY ("user_id")
) WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

Comment: What was the exact command you used, how did you run it, and what was the exact full response?

Answer (score 1):

If you've already created the table, you can use this query to rename the column

```sql
ALTER TABLE users RENAME COLUMN photo_url TO test;
```

otherwise simply recreate your table with the new column name.

More information on the `ALTER TABLE` command can be found in the [PostgreSQL Docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html).